# nodejs writeFile only working with admin permssions

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

I currently learning electron and I would like to write a config file in the same dir than the exe file. This is my code:

```
     var save = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/config.json")
    save = {
      storein : savegame
  }
  fs.writeFile("./config.json", JSON.stringify(save), function(error){
//other stuff
})
```

But if I run this without administrator permissions, its not working, only if I run the .exe as an admin. If I use `electron app` it works too

Comment: This isn't a node problem, this depends on the setup of your app and the permissions of the directory it's installed in.

Comment: Is there a way I can change the app settings so it can only be run as administrator